# Goerli more expensive than Ethereum Mainnet

Tags: transactions, gas-price, goerli

> Currently, a transaction on **Goerli** is more expensive than the Ethereum mainnet.
> Why is that the case?
>
> > Here is the contract:

```sol
contract Test {
  uint x;

  function test() external {
    x += 1;
  }
}
```

> 1. Here is the goerli deployment transaction which costs **0.0032 ETH**:
>
> > https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x817048406ca845764580dbd8a6c10280255bdb9dc5835ee587482e0da0efb837

> 2. Here is the ethereum mainnet transaction cost of **0.0022 ETH**:
>    [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gas price is not constant. Although gas is dependent on the storage of the contract, the network congestion plays a great role.

Maybe when you are deploying the contract, the Goerli network congested more than usual. While the main net is free.

And there are other factors such as speeding up by providing more ether etc.

[image: Gas Fee]

Look at the image above. It is what I got now when I tried to deploy a contract on goerli. So that might be the reason.

[image: Etherscan]

Also look at this image. There is something called base fee. Which is the minimum amount of fee required to include your transaction in the network. And the price can go above that based on network congestion.

You can read more about the gas fees [here](https://www.coindesk.com/learn/what-are-ethereum-gas-fees/).

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I knew that the Goerli was probably busy, but I wasn't sure whether it is likely for it to go above the mainnet, but it seems it can.

Answer (score 1):

Goerli  is now the worst network to develop on, first the faucets are all giving like 0.1ETH, then the gas is sometimes 60-90 Gwei, deploying a standard erc20 contract @ 60 Gwei will burn about 0.09 ETH, making the 0.1 ETH useless  And I don't think the Ethereum team cares anymore about the devs, anyway my solution is to use another network. I prefer FTM testnet, they give 5 FTM in their official faucet and its 100% compatible with ETH.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, a transaction on Goerli is more expensive than the Ethereum mainnet. Why is that the case?

Goerli ETH is free, so it cannot be more expensive than mainnet. Whatever is the gas fee at Goerli is irrelevant.

Comment: My question is not quite related to this, rather than USD based expensiveness I was more talking about ETH wise expensiveness, and since goerli is a decentralized network and adjusts its gas fees according to the congestion of the network, I couldn't reason why it requires higher ETH

Answer (score 0):

My contract deployment cost:

[image]

And that's their faucet:

[image]

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

use https://www.buildbear.io/ With BuildBear you can create a private Testnet with a build faucet.